# Recursion: Binary to Decimal

Tags: java, recursion, binary, decimal

I am working on a recursive method that takes a binary number as a string and displays its decimal equivalent. I am unsure if my base cases are correct. Also, am I properly imposing recursion within the method?

```
public  static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter a binary string ");
    String binary = input.nextLine(); 

    System.out.println("The decimal equivalent of " + binary + " is "+ binary2Decimal(binary));
}

//MethodOverloading
public static int binary2Decimal(String binary){
    return binary2Decimal(binary,0, binary.length()-1);
    }
public static void binary2Decimal(String binary, int low, int high){
        int temp=0;
        if(binary.charAt(high) == 0)
            temp *= 2;
        else if(binary.charAt(high) == 1)
            temp = (temp * 2) + 1;
        return binary2Decimal(binary,low,high -1)+temp;

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your base case? And why are you using recursion for this?

Comment: return type of `binary2Decimal` is should be `int`

Comment: You don't have any base cases; so no, they aren't correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* a base case; `binary2Decimal` (3-arg version) *always* calls itself.  (Since the only thing changing from one call to the next is `high`, your base case should probably involve that somehow.)

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

Your method:
public static void binary2Decimal(String binary, int low, int high)
should have a return type of int instead of void.

You aren't using your variable low (so you can get rid of it if you want).

You need a base case with some code like:

```
if (high == 0) {
  return somevalue;
}
else {
  return binary2Decimal(binary,low,high -1)+temp;
}
```

Otherwise you will get into an infinite loop, and your method will recurse indefinitely.